# Uncaught TypeError: todo.classList is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I don't understand why this error is shown. I define 3 to 4 functions but all are working properly but when I write this function its through me a error. What could be its cause?

***Uncaught TypeError: todo.classList is undefined***

```js
function filterTodo(e){
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    console.log(todos);
    todos.forEach(function(todo){
        switch(e.target.value){
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
            case "completed":
                if(todo.classList.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
            case "uncompleted":
                if(!todo.classList.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve]. It could be something as trivial as having text nodes in the `todoList`. Those nodes have no classlist. Without relevant html we are left guessing

Comment: Consider using `children` instead?

Answer (score 2):

keep the `ul` empty in your **HTML**

```
 <div class="todo-continer">
    <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a member of Element. `todo` is the iterator of `todos`, which was initialized as

const todos = todoList.childNodes;

[childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) is a `NodeList`, which has [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) items inside of it. Node is an interface, one of its implementations is `Element`. So, the troubling item is a `Node`, but not an `Element`. I would find out what it is if I were you. A simple fix would be

```
todo.classList && todo.classList.contains("completed")
```

at both occasions, but I would dig deeper to find out what the issue is if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

I almost spent 2 hours figuring out what's wrong as I was following exact steps of the *JavaScript Project Todo App by Dev Ed on YouTube* -
I was getting the same error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: todo.classList is undefined
```

After hunting a lot I found couple of solutions like it's childNodes thus loop through the array thus I even tried

`todo[0].style.display = "flex";`

But providing index also didn't work. Later I thought of converting it in to array function and the code worked just perfect.

Here is the code:

```js
function filterTodo(e){
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach((todo)=> {
  
    switch(e.target.value){
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case"completed":
      if(todo.classList.contains('task-completed')){
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else{
          todo.style.display = "none";      }
      break;
      case "pending":
                if(!todo.classList.contains('task-completed')){
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;

    }
  });
}
```